# How I can Launch "play store"(google) in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, unity-container

How I can Launch "play store"(google) in unity by c#code?  I could not open play store app.help me plaese This question 
means open link my games in " google play store " Application for example link :com.ds.aa  in google play
help me please

Answer (score 5):

First, you need a button inside your game that links you to the App Store. Then you want to add an OnClick() listener to the button with the following code:

```
Application.OpenURL ("market://details?id=" + Application.productName);
```

Assuming you have connected your game to the Play Store, this should link you to your games page. If you want to just open the Play Store in general, I think you should check out this question:

[Application.OpenURL to open google play store?](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1119574/applicationopenurl-to-open-google-play-store.html)

Comment: very very Thanks D.Christodoulou It worked...so for what is code for launch facebook app?????

Comment: To launch the facebook app, check out this answer: [Facebook from Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48042767/open-facebook-app-via-unity-script-on-android). Also, if the answer helped you, consider accepting it (clicking the check icon under the upvote/downvote buttons) to help other users find the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, How can I launch twitter and Instagram in unity   ?  D.Christodoulou

Comment: shouldn't it be package name and not product name?

Answer (score 2):

Application.OpenURL ("market://details?id=" + packageName)

1. facebook packageName = com.facebook.katana
2. instagram packageName = com.instagram.android
3. twitter packageName = com.twitter.android

You can open any application on the Google Play Market.

How to find the package name

1. open this link in pc  - https://play.google.com
2. Search for the app you want
3. click for the app you want
4. look your browser address bar, you can find package name

Comment: hi, sorry for oot question. But it simillar, can i create my own schema. for example `foo://` ?